# O programa salta uma linha de código a frente

Tags: c++

Quando eu executo o programa abaixo, não me pede pelo nome da avaria e salta logo para a descrição.

```
  void gestor::addavaria()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    int opc;
    string descricao;
    string nome;
    int tipo;
    opc = submenu();
    avaria*av = NULL;
    switch (opc)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Introduza o tipo de avaria!" << endl;
        cin >> tipo;
        cout << " Introduza o nome da avaria!" << endl;
        getline(cin, nome);
        cout << "Introduza a descrição da avaria!" << endl;
        getline(cin,descricao);
        av = new avaria (tipo,nome,descricao);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "nada!\n" << endl;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou tentando executar seu código e estou tendo problemas aqui, poste seu código completo ai por favor, to meio sem tempo aqui, mas vou tentar ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para chamar o `getline` depois de um `cin >> ...` você precisa limpar o *buffer* para retirar o caractere de nova linha que ficou no momento que apertou <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Pode utilizar um [**`cin.ignore()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) para isso:

```
void gestor::addavaria()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    int opc;
    string descricao;
    string nome;
    int tipo;
    opc = submenu();
    avaria*av = NULL;
    switch (opc)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Introduza o tipo de avaria!" << endl;
        cin >> tipo;
        cin.ignore(); // Alteração aqui.
        cout << " Introduza o nome da avaria!" << endl;
        getline(cin, nome);
        cout << "Introduza a descrição da avaria!" << endl;
        getline(cin,descricao);
        av = new avaria (tipo,nome,descricao);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "nada!\n" << endl;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```